# Use ng-model with condition

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs in my project.

I have below code in my HTML:

```
 <div class="MT10" ng-init="getPaymentDetailsById()">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> Name:</label>
                <span class="rightside">
                        <input type="text" value="" ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.name" >
               </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP :</label>
            <span class="rightside">       
                <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="paymentDetails.id" ng-disabled="appId">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP KEY:</label>
              <span class="rightside">       
                  <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.appKey" > 
              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP SECRET:</label>
              <span class="rightside">       
                  <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.appSecret">
              </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

now

```
<span class="rightside">       
                    <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="paymentDetails.id" ng-disabled="appId">
                </span>
```

This code displays some data in my textbox. And I want to display that data in textbox in both scenario, that is **while editing and while posting** new data to server. So it just displays it while editing but not when I want to post new data to server. Basically this textbox will always have some value pre-filled in it. So i am guessing I have to use some condition on that. So please help me how to achieve that.

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, please mark is as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your question, you could do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentDetails.id" ng-disabled="appId" ng-show="adding"/>

<span ng-hide="adding">{{paymentDetails.id}}</span>
```

And then in your controller you could control the variable:

```
$scope.adding = true
```

and set it to false based on some condition

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are getting at. Without seeing your JS file it would be very hard to give you a good example, however using $scope.value in your JS and setting the text to {{value}} in your HTML should provide the desired result.

Comment: see, basically I want to set value to textbox based on 2 scenarios. If i am editing the result then it should set prefilled value to textbox. and when i am adding new fresh data it should set some value in $scope.value

Comment: Ah then NexusDuck has nailed it! Happy Coding!